# Will an AWS EBS volume that has been attached to another instance, still delete on terminate of the original instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume, terminate

I have an instance that has a root volume set to terminate on delete.  I need to spin up a new instance and attach the volume to the new instance.  My concern is that the volume will Delete when I terminate the original instance.  I know, it seems the volume should delete on terminate to it's attached instance, not the original instance it was assigned to... just checking.  I will find out soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

The EBS volume will only "delete on terminate" on the currently attached instance, regardless of the original instance state - and only if you specify it should.